# Spring-Batch : How do I return custom exit code on invalid record with exception in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a spring batch task in which I have few records some are valid and some are invalid in the input file.On valid records, it should write to the output file and for the invalid record, it should write to error file with some exception thrown from the processor.So the problem is when something is written to error file it should set exit code as 3.I have tried many approaches but it is not able to set exit code.It even terminates the instance for that record when exception occur so it doesn't call writer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should take the tour and read the [MCVE] section in order to maximize your chances of getting positive feedback and assistance on your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to use an exception here. As a general rule of thumb, it's best to avoid using exceptions for expected business logic. Instead, consider simply using your `ItemProcessor` to return a `GoodObject` (or the original item) if the record is valid and a `BadObject` if the record is invalid.

Then, leverage a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` to send the good records to one file `ItemWriter` and the bad ones to the error file `ItemWriter`.

Finally, there are a number of ways of determining whether or not any "bad" records are encountered. One simple way would be to put a class-level `boolean` in your `ItemProcessor` and then leverage the `StepExecutionListener` `afterStep` hook to check the flag and set the `ExitCode`.

```
public class ValidatingItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Input, AbstractItem>, StepExecutionListener {

    private boolean itemFailed = false;

    @Override
    public AbstractItem process(final Input item) throws Exception {
        if (item.isValid()) {
            return new GoodItem();
        }
        itemFailed = true;
        return new BadItem();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        //no-op
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (itemFailed) {
            return new ExitStatus("3");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```